# We are interested in an API to browse the Labor Dept. form 5500 datasets

Tags: labor

Is there an API in development to allow search/transmissions of the 5500 form datasets?
https://www.dol.gov/agencies/ebsa/about-ebsa/our-activities/public-disclosure/foia/form-5500-datasets